# Velocity inline if-else block to add a classname

Tags: velocity

I want to set a conditional classname on some element in velocity.

For example, if I currently have:

```
<div class="aClass">some content</div>
```

then I want to add another class name conditionally. I thought something like this would work:

```
<div class="aClass #if($foo == 'bar')someClass{else}anotherClass#end">some content</div>
```

but it doesn't work that way, and neither `someClass` nor `anotherClass` is being added.

How can I achieve this desired behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need # before **else**

```
<div class="aClass #if($foo == 'bar')someClass#{else}anotherClass#end">some content</div>
```

Comment: Close enough... it was actually `#{else}`. but thanks for giving me a direction

Comment: both #{else} and {#else} are also OK bro!

Comment: `{#else}` yielded a weird result: `class="aClass }anotherClass"`. I don't want the `}`

Comment: That's cool. Like I said, it's enough that you pushed me towards the solution